# calculate the distance of routes of two railway station in google map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, driving-directions

I know with the Google API, it is possible to calculate the distances of routes between two points, however most examples I see is the direction service calculate distances on the car/ walking/ bicycle routes.

From the code, it is possible to get the distance between two big cities on railway (code below), but I want to also get the distances of 16 segments, which are small stations between two big cities. How to?

```
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
 var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer(rendererOptions);
 directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

 var request = {
       origin: 'Chester', 
       destination: 'Liverpool',
       travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT,
       unitSystem:google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
 };

 directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
   if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

   ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
     directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
    var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
    for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
      var steps = legs[i].steps;
      for (j=0;j<steps.length;j++) {

        var transitMode = steps[j].travel_mode;

        if (transitMode == "TRANSIT") {
                var vehicle = steps[j].transit.line.vehicle.type;
                if (vehicle == "HEAVY_RAIL") {          
                  var nextSegment = steps[j].path;

          console.log('segment   '+nextSegment.length);
          for (k=0;k<nextSegment.length;k++) {
         console.log(nextSegment[k].hb+"     "+nextSegment[k].ib);
             route_polyline.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
          }

                  console.log('rail');                       
                }
        }
      }
    }
    route_polyline.setMap(map);
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you require the shortest distance between stations rather than the distance travelled? If so you require a database of railway stations and to use the [**Haversine**](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) formula to calculate this. I have a [**Demo**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php) which uses this to find railway stations within a radius of a location. This can be modified to suit your requirements

Comment: thanks, david, what I want to get is the real distances between two stations. For example, from liverpool to chaster, there are 16 small stations, and I want calculate the distance of consequent stations.

Comment: A combination between David's answer (great map btw) of using a database and checking each step to see if it is within say 50 meters of one of those points would give you a station for that leg. At which point you could grab the distance of each step, adding them together to get the total travelled distance between each station if you dont want the straight line as David suggested.